# Word C# Addinn for Word 2003 and Word 2007

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

Is it possible to write Word (Office) Addins in C#, which works in 2003 and 2007?

Comment: This is a really vague question. It is possible, just remember that each subsequent version of Office (and therefore VBA) has had features added, and others made redundant so make sure you test on every version.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refer :

http://netoffice.codeplex.com/

This enables you to create Addins for all supported versions of MS Office.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean that the add-in would have to work in both versions simultaneously, but writing add-ins for both versions separately can be done in C#.

Visual Studio 2010, for example, even provides templates for Office 2010 and 2007 add-ins.